# How to capture the name of a function on ultisnips plugin?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I have created a **guard** snippet (ultisnips) in order to add on my existing
functions:

```
snippet guard "add guard to functions" b
if !exists('*${1:func_name}')
   ${VISUAL}
endif
${0:jump here <C-j>}
endsnippet
```

At the moment I have to type the "func_name" at the top and 
it has to be equal at the name captured in the visual section, 
anyone have a better suggestion or any improvement to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
snippet guard "add guard to functions" b
if !exists('*`!p snip.rv = re.search('\S+\s+(\S+)\(', snip.v.text.splitlines()[0]).group(1)`')
    ${VISUAL}
endif
${0:jump here <C-j>}
endsnippet
```

The `` `!p snip.rv = ...` `` part is a python interpolation. The evaluation of the expression to the right of the assignment operator after `snip.rv` replaces everything between the backticks.

Here the expression is:

```
re.search('\S+\s+(\S+)\(', snip.v.text.splitlines()[0]).group(1)
```

- `snip.v.text` allows you to refer to the last visually-selected text in a python interpolation.
- [`.splitlines()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172454/9780968) allows you to split the lines of the visual selection in a list.
- `snip.v.text.splitlines()[0]` grabs the first line in the selection.
- `re.search('\S+\s+(\S+)\(', ...).group(1)` extracts the function name from this line.

---

If you make a mistake when selecting the function, the first line may not match the regex, in which case an error will be raised.

Inside the python interpolation, you can use a `try`, `except` construct to [catch the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667014/9780968):

```
snippet guard "add guard to functions" b
if !exists('*`!p
try:
    func_name = re.search('\S+\s+(\S+)\(', snip.v.text.splitlines()[0]).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    func_name = ''
snip.rv = func_name
`')
    ${VISUAL}
endif
${0:jump here <C-j>}
endsnippet
```

Comment: The regex could be less permissive? While a function could be `function` or `fun` or `functi`, it must start with `fu`, so you could instead use `r'\bfu\S*\s+(\S+)\('` to ensure it starts with 'fu' (and \b to prevent matching something like `:Snafu`). (There's lots of other possibilities for false positives, but this seems like the most important fix.)